# Expectation of two square gaussian

Tags: probability

I'm looking for an easy way (I mean, don't compute the double integral) to compute $\mathbb E[X^2Y^2]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are standard gaussians with correlation $\rho$.

Comment: I assume you mean that $X$ and $Y$ are **jointly** Gaussian standard (zero-mean, unit variance) random variables with correlation $\rho$. If so, I suggest you try the law of iterated expectation:  $E[X^2Y^2] = E[E[X^2Y^2\mid Y]]$ since $E[X^2Y^2\mid Y]$ is easy to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian vectors, then $X|Y=y$ has a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance $K$ where

$\mu = E[X|Y=y] = E[X] + cov(X,Y)cov(Y)^{-1}(y-E[Y])$

and

$K = cov(X) - cov(X,Y) cov(Y)^{-1} cov(Y,X)$.

(See proposition 3.4.4 in these [notes](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~hajek/Papers/randomprocesses.html) for details).

Now, $E[X^2Y^2] = E[E[X^2Y^2|Y]]=E[Y^2E[X^2|Y]]$. You can calculate $E[X^2|Y]$ since you have the distribution of $X|Y$ above, by noting that $E[X^2|Y] -(E[X|Y])^2 = cov(X|Y)$. Then, you have some thing which is an expectation in $Y$ which you can easily compute, since the moments of a (standard) Gaussian are known to be $0$ for odd ones, and $(n-1)!!$ where the $!!$ denotes a double factorial (and from the standard normal, you can get the result for your particular case).

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked !